# Javascript, Object prototype - avoid writing full path

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, fallback, spl-autoload-register

I know my title may not be very clear, I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I know that modifying prototypes is generally frowned upon, and for good reason, so I'm trying to figure out a way to do so without adding any more than one item to the prototype.

I know that I could simply do something along the lines of

```
Object.prototype.collection = {};
Object.prototype.collection.method1 = function(){ . . . };
Object.prototype.collection.method2 = function(){ . . . };
Object.prototype.collection.method3 = function(){ . . . };
etc.
```

And then whenever I wanted to use one of the methods I could call

```
objectInstance.collection.method1();
```

The problem with this is that eventually it can get pretty wordy and tedious, not to mention if you're calling a hundred methods from this collection, the word 'collection' a hundred times is redundant and a waste of bytes.

So I was hoping for a technique of creating methods in this manner, without having to write the full path every time. i.e. I could write

```
objectInstance.method1();
```

And it would know right where to look.

My thought process at this point is that obviously calling the latter would throw a `method does not exist` error. But I'm curious if there is any manner of intercepting this error?

For instance, in PHP there is the spl_autoload_register() function, which is called whenever a class has not been defined, allowing you to do whatever is necessary to load/define it. Is there any equivalent strategy for this circumstance?

Maybe I could add a secondary 'fallback' method, like so:

```
Object.prototype.fallback = function( undefinedMethod ){

    if(this.collection.undefinedMethod){

        this.collection.undefinedMethod();

    }
};
```

And just have this called every time a method is undefined, passing in the method.

Any help for anything along these lines, or if it's even possible, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: I'm going to look into that a bit more, but it looks like exactly what I need! Thanks so much!

Comment: Just make sure your host supports this and it should do what you need. Let me know if this suits you, I could post this as an answer.

Comment: I did some research and yes, proxy is exactly what I need to do what I'm proposing! Thank goodness for ES6! Are you aware of any polyfills or hacks for support on internet explorer? I'll look for some myself, but I figured I'd ask first. And absolutely, if you make this an answer then I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As far as I remember, there were some problems with polyfilling this under IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible approaches is to use the newly introduced `Proxy` that allows you to intercept arbitrary calls to object members.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

An example from the MDN

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name){
    return name in target?
        target[name] :
        37;
  }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
p.a = 1;
p.b = undefined;

console.log(p.a, p.b); // 1, undefined
console.log('c' in p, p.c); // false, 37
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do strange things like that. If you want to do it the good way, don't pollute object you don't own. Just create your own constructor.

```
class MyClass {
  method1(){ . . . };
  method2(){ . . . };
  method3(){ . . . };
}
```

then your methods will be available to `MyClass` instances.

If you want to use your methods on all `Object` instances, well, you need to pollute `Object.prototype`. You ask for workarounds, but they would basically have the same problems.

It may be less problematic if you define your methods as not enumerable, this way they won't appear in `for-in` loops.

```
Object.prototype.method1 = function(){ . . . };
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'method1', {enumerable:false});
```

Comment: That's just my point though, I can't do that. For sake of length I didn't include this in my question, but the point of this is to be able to create a custom back-end/framework for a series of plugins that I'm making. And I also want to make the framework available for others to build on top of. Again, for sake of length, just know that I have good reason to not use any other framework. I'd like to avoid the Jquery-like issue of not being able to use custom methods on variables not declared using the framework, and that's why I won't take that route. I appreciate your insight and time though.